# unable to convert retrieved list from cache to desired format

Tags: c#, list, c#-4.0, caching

I am trying to add list of cloned objects to cache so that when i modify the original source, it does not change the objects in the cache. However, i am not able to add them to the cache as desired type.

`List<ComputerStatus> clonedCopy = listOfComputers.Select(s => s.Clone()).ToList();` throws me an error saying `"Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<object>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<MvcWebAPI.Models.ComputerStatus>'"`

If i just add it to the cache as

```
var clonedCopy = listOfComputers.Select(s => s.Clone());
CacheManager.AddToCache("myKey", clonedCopy, CacheItemPriority.Default, 30);
```

and then try to retrieve it as

```
List<ComputerStatus> listOfComputers = new List<ComputerStatus>();
listOfComputers = CacheManager.GetFromCache("myKey") as List<ComputerStatus>;
```

then it returns null

This is how my ComputerStatus class looks like:

```
public class ComputerStatus : ICloneable
{
    public string Property1 { get; set; }
    public string Property2 { get; set; }
    public string Property3 { get; set; }

    public object Clone()
    {
        return this.MemberwiseClone();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried

```
List<ComputerStatus> clonedCopy = listOfComputers.Select(s => (ComputerStatus)s.Clone()).ToList();
```

Your problem is because the default implementation of `Clone` from `IClonable` returns an object of type `object` and so the type of your select is `IEnumerable<object>` which ToList turns into `List<object>`.  By casting the result of clone as a `ComputerStatus` you change the select to `IEnumerable<ComputerStatus>` and so the `ToList()` turns it into `List<ComputerStatus>`.

Your second attempt fails because you are storing an `IEnumerable<object>` which is not castable to `List<ComputerStatus>` hence getting `null` using the safe cast.  Additionally you need to be careful storing without the `ToList()` because the enumerable will deferred until you actually come to read it and so the changes to the collection will affect it, or a collection modified exception may be raised.